# Descent along purely inseparable morphisms

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, descent

- What properties of $\mathbf{F}_p$-algebras descent along powers of the absolute Frobenius?
- What properties of morphisms of $\mathbf{F}_p$-algebras descent along powers of the absolute Frobenius?

Is there a general reference for descent along purely inseparable morphisms?

Comment: In some 'nice' situations (e.g. smooth varieties over $\mathbb F_q$), the Frobenius is flat, so you can use fpqc descent. More generally, for algebras a general setting where a lot of stuff works is [universally injective ring homomorphisms](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/08WE), but this also puts some conditions on your ring (e.g. it better be reduced for the Frobenius to be injective). What type of situation are you interested in?